# Plot histograms per row using gt tables - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr, gt

I want to create a gt table where I see some metrics like number of observations, mean and median, and I want a column with its histogram. For this question I will use the iris dataset.

I have recently learned how to put a plot in a tibble using this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(gt)
my_tibble <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  group_by(Vars) %>%
  summarise(obs = n(),
            mean = round(mean(Values),2),
            median = round(median(Values),2), 
            plots = list(ggplot(cur_data(), aes(Values)) + geom_histogram()))
```

Now I want to use the plots column for plotting an histogram per variable, so I have tried this:

```
my_tibble %>%
  mutate(ggplot = NA) %>%
  gt() %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(vars(ggplot)),
    fn = function(x) {
      map(.$plots,ggplot_image)
    }
  )
```

But it returns me an error:

```
Error in body[[col]][stub_df$rownum_i %in% loc$rows] <- fn(body[[col]][stub_df$rownum_i %in%  : 
  replacement has length zero
```

The gt table should be like this:
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to loop over the `plots`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(gt)
library(ggplot2)
iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  nest_by(Vars) %>%
  mutate(n = nrow(data),
         mean = round(mean(data$Values), 2), 
         median = round(median(data$Values), 2), 
         plots = list(ggplot(data, aes(Values)) + geom_histogram()), .keep = "unused") %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(ggplot = NA) %>%
  {dat <- .
  dat %>%
    select(-plots) %>%
    gt() %>%
  text_transform(locations = cells_body(c(ggplot)),
                 fn = function(x) {
                  map(dat$plots, ggplot_image, height = px(100))
                 }
                 
                 
                 )
  }
```

-check for the output
[image]

Comment: This one is really good!

Comment: @Alexis do you need `my_tibble$plots2 <- map(my_tibble$plots, ~ {
  tibble(ggplot = NA) %>%
    gt() %>%
    text_transform(
      locations = cells_body(columns = ggplot),
      fn = function(x) {
        .x %>%
          ggplot_image(height = px(200))
      }
    )
  
})`

Comment: Hello @akrun, your answer gave me some ideas on how to achieve the expected table. Thank you again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I was a bit busy, couldn't try.  Thanks

Comment: @Alexis I updated the post.  I tweaked your code and made this in one single %>% so that we don't have to redo the pivot_longer two times

Comment: Thank you @akrun! What a great answer!, compact and clear! I see that you call all the data with the `.` placeholder and then create the gt table. I new thing to learn for me. Have a great day!

Answer (score 5):

After reviewing the excellent ideas from @akrun and @TarJae, I have this solution that gives the required gt table:

```
plots <- iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  group_by(Vars) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(plot = map(data, 
                    function(df) df %>% 
                      ggplot(aes(Values)) + 
                      geom_histogram())) %>%
  select(-data)

iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") %>%
  group_by(Vars) %>%
  summarise(obs = n(),
            mean = round(mean(Values),2),
            median = round(median(Values),2)) %>%
  mutate(ggplot = NA) %>%
  gt() %>%
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(vars(ggplot)),
    fn = function(x) {
      map(plots$plot, ggplot_image, height = px(100))
    }
  )
```

And this is the table:
[image]

I had to create the plot outside the output table, so I could call it in the gt table.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** See comments:

For your purposes in accordance with a shiny app you may use `summarytools` see here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/introduction.html

it is compatible with r shiny!

Here is a small example:

```
library(summarytools)
dfSummary(iris, 
          plain.ascii  = FALSE, 
          style        = "grid", 
          graph.magnif = 0.75, 
          valid.col    = FALSE,
          tmp.img.dir  = "/tmp")

view(dfSummary(iris))
```

[image]

Try this:

```
library(skimr)
skim(iris)
```

```
  skim_variable n_missing complete_rate  mean    sd    p0   p25   p50   p75  p100 hist 
* <chr>             <int>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1 Sepal.Length          0             1  5.84 0.828   4.3   5.1  5.8    6.4   7.9 ▆▇▇▅▂
2 Sepal.Width           0             1  3.06 0.436   2     2.8  3      3.3   4.4 ▁▆▇▂▁
3 Petal.Length          0             1  3.76 1.77    1     1.6  4.35   5.1   6.9 ▇▁▆▇▂
4 Petal.Width           0             1  1.20 0.762   0.1   0.3  1.3    1.8   2.5 ▇▁▇▅▃
```

Comment: Hi @TarJae, that solution is good, but there is a problem with the special characters it uses to plot the histogram (some of these characters don't work with shiny for example), that's the reason I want to implement it with gt. Anyway thank you! (to be honest I want something like the skimr, but with other metrics like skewness, kurtosis, etc)

Comment: Give me some seconds. Currently working on another question, but it is possible with shiny. I did it. will back soon!

Comment: I am working with a complex example that Thomas Mock uses for plotting sparklines per row, besides the great answer that akrun gives, it will be a good question and answers for other readers.

Comment: Please see my update. It was not `skimr` but `summarytools` I used in the shiny app!

Comment: Hi @TarJae, thank you for your answer, I really appreciate the help you and others in SO give to the members of this community. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

The recently created `gtExtras` package has also implemented a solution to inline histograms in `gt` tables using `gtExtras::gt_plt_dist()`.

```
iris |>
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") |>
  group_by(Vars) |>
  summarise(obs = n(),
            mean = round(mean(Values),2),
            median = round(median(Values),2),
            iris_data = list(Values) # adds the data as a list to the end of the df
            ) |>
  gt() |>
   gt_plt_dist(iris_data, 
               type = "histogram",
               same_limit = F, # ensures each histogram can have its own axis range
               fill_color = "lightgrey", # changed color for a little more visibility of the bins
               line_color = "black"
               )
```

[image]

You can even extend the `Vars` groupings further as headers to subgroup the results by `Species`:

```
iris |>
  pivot_longer(-Species, 
               names_to = "Vars", 
               values_to = "Values") |>
  group_by(Species,Vars) |>
  summarise(obs = n(),
            mean = round(mean(Values),2),
            median = round(median(Values),2),
            iris_data = list(Values) # adds the data as a list to the end of the df
            ) |>
  gt() |>
   gt_plt_dist(iris_data, 
               type = "histogram",
               same_limit = F, # ensures each histogram can have its own axis range
               fill_color = "lightgrey", # changed color for a little more visibility of the bins
               line_color = "black"
               )
```

[image]

`gtExtras` also allows density plots, sparklines, scatter plots, and more!

Resources for further reading on the `gtExtras` package:

- https://themockup.blog/posts/2022-06-13-gtextras-cran/
- https://jthomasmock.github.io/gtExtras/reference/gt_sparkline.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gtExtras/gtExtras.pdf